# What are the issues in my PHP function that are causing a fatal error to occur?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, boolean, execute

`getUserIDForEmail` is supposed to query the MySQL DB and search for an email address and get the corresponding user ID.

This test case:

```
$adminId = getUserIDForEmail("a.h@outlook.com");
```

Results in this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /.../public_html/db.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /.../public_html/register.php(5): getUserIDForEmail('a.h@outlook.com') #1 {main} thrown in /.../public_html/db.php on line 51

Line 51 is:

```
$stmt = $stmt->execute();
```

From this code:

```
/* code omitted here */

$conn = new mysqli(DB['servername'], DB['username'], DB['password'], DB['dbname']);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

session_start();

/* code omitted here */

/**
 * Query database for registered email and get user ID.
 * 
 * @param {String} $email
 * @return {Number} $userID
 */
function getUserIDForEmail($email) {

    global $conn;

    $userID = -1;
    $sql = '';
    $stmt = null;
    $row = null;

    if (empty($email)) {
        throw new Exception("Email is undefined");
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new Exception("Email is not correctly formatted");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `UserAccount` WHERE `email` = ?";

    /* Avoid SQL injection */
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt = $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt = $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // first result
            $userID = $row["id"];
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }

    return $userID;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind_param()` returns a `boolean` and you are reassigning that to `$stmt`.  You are doing the same with `execute()`. Just call the methods on the `$stmt` object:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then you will have issues with this, as there is no `$result`:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

So just `fetch()` from the statement:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something silly like that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

mysqli_stmt::bind_param returns a Boolean look: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

simply remove '$stmt = ' from #50 line.